# Django form checking

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-validation

I have the following form:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="selectTeamOne">

            {% for x in currentTeams %}

                {% if x.teamid != 66 %}

                    <option value={{x.teamid}}>{{x.teamname}}</option>

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        </select>

        <select name="selectTeamTwo">

            {% for x in currentTeams %}

                <option value={{x.teamid}}>{{x.teamname}}</option>

            {% endfor %}

        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

This is driven by the following view:

```
def selectteams(request, soccerseason, fixturematchday):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponse("Two different teams were selected.")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Two different teams were not selected.")


    fixtures = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(soccerseason=soccerseason,fixturematchday=fixturematchday).order_by('fixturedate')

    currentTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam=1).order_by('teamname')

    cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.filter(campaignno=389100069).order_by('campaignno')

    return render(request, 'straightred/test.html',
                  {'fixtures' : fixtures,
                   'currentTeams' : currentTeams,
                   'cantSelectTeams' : cantSelectTeams,
                   'soccerseason' : soccerseason,
                   'fixturematchday' : fixturematchday})
```

I just wondered the best way to check if the the user has selected the same team twice from the drop down lists and return the relevant HttpResponse as you can see above.

Any advice to point me in the right direction is appreciated.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: I am not using Django to create the form itself.  Is this a big no no in the first place?

Comment: Forms are a powerful tool, so it is better to use them where you can. To create a select from a model or a queryset you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: I will rebuild it and embrace forms in django. Will keep you updated :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you put your comment as an answer so I may accept it :)

Comment: I guess you got your django form to work :P. You can add extra hints for users by hiding the selected field from the other select with javascript, but that's just for easy of use. Having the validation on server first is way more important.

Comment: i did indeed :) got me thinking about tweaking my models too... my brain hurts lol.  thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce server level validation on django forms:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

From the docs for django 1.8:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if "help" not in subject:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                    "CC'ing yourself."
                )
```